# QGIS - trying to draw polygons

Tags: qgis, polygon

I´m complety new in this game, so unfortunately I havent figured out how I get my data into QGIS onto a map.

I got my data delievered in a Excel sheet (no words need) and it looks like this.

I have absolutely no clue how to get this data in QGIS (or any other free software or maybe a website?)

{'results': [{'search_id': '10_2023-03-01T08:00:00.0', 'shapes': [{'shell': [{'lat': 53.2417, 'lng': 10.35903}, {'lat': 53.240803, 'lng': 10.360527}, {'lat': 53.240803, 'lng': 10.363522}, {'lat': 53.238106, 'lng': 10.368014}, {'lat': 53.23721, 'lng': 10.366517}, {'lat': 53.23721, 'lng': 10.363522}, {'lat': 53.23631, 'lng': 10.362024}, {'lat': 53.235413, 'lng': 10.363522}, {'lat': 53.235413, 'lng': 10.378496}, {'lat': 53.232716, 'lng': 10.382988}, {'lat': 53.23092, 'lng': 10.379993}, {'lat': 53.23002, 'lng': 10.381491}, {'lat': 53.23002, 'lng': 10.384485}, {'lat': 53.22822, 'lng': 10.387481}, {'lat': 53.229122, 'lng': 10.388978}, {'lat': 53.23092, 'lng': 10.388978}, {'lat': 53.231815, 'lng': 10.390475}, {'lat': 53.23002, 'lng': 10.39347}, {'lat': 53.231815, 'lng': 10.396464}, {'lat': 53.231815, 'lng': 10.39946}, {'lat': 53.232716, 'lng': 10.400957}, {'lat': 53.234512, 'lng': 10.400957}, {'lat': 53.235413, 'lng': 10.402454}, {'lat': 53.235413, 'lng': 10.405449}, {'lat': 53.238106, 'lng': 10.409942}, {'lat': 53.2435, 'lng': 10.409942}, {'lat': 53.244396, 'lng': 10.408444}, {'lat': 53.244396, 'lng': 10.405449}, {'lat': 53.245296, 'lng': 10.403952}, {'lat': 53.247093, 'lng': 10.403952}, {'lat': 53.24799, 'lng': 10.405449}, {'lat': 53.24799, 'lng': 10.408444}, {'lat': 53.24889, 'lng': 10.409942}, {'lat': 53.250687, 'lng': 10.406946}, {'lat': 53.252483, 'lng': 10.406946}, {'lat': 53.253384, 'lng': 10.408444}, {'lat': 53.251587, 'lng': 10.411439}, {'lat': 53.252483, 'lng': 10.412936}, {'lat': 53.262367, 'lng': 10.396464}, {'lat': 53.262367, 'lng': 10.39347}, {'lat': 53.263268, 'lng': 10.391973}, {'lat': 53.265064, 'lng': 10.391973}, {'lat': 53.26596, 'lng': 10.390475}, {'lat': 53.265064, 'lng': 10.388978}, {'lat': 53.26147, 'lng': 10.388978}, {'lat': 53.26057, 'lng': 10.387481}, {'lat': 53.262367, 'lng': 10.384485}, {'lat': 53.262367, 'lng': 10.381491}, {'lat': 53.26147, 'lng': 10.379993}, {'lat': 53.25967, 'lng': 10.379993}, {'lat': 53.258774, 'lng': 10.378496}, {'lat': 53.258774, 'lng': 10.375501}, {'lat': 53.257874, 'lng': 10.374003}, {'lat': 53.256077, 'lng': 10.374003}, {'lat': 53.25518, 'lng': 10.375501}, {'lat': 53.25518, 'lng': 10.378496}, {'lat': 53.25428, 'lng': 10.379993}, {'lat': 53.25316, 'lng': 10.381491}, {'lat': 53.252483, 'lng': 10.374003}, {'lat': 53.25518, 'lng': 10.369512}, {'lat': 53.25518, 'lng': 10.363522}, {'lat': 53.249786, 'lng': 10.354538}, {'lat': 53.249786, 'lng': 10.351542}, {'lat': 53.24889, 'lng': 10.350045}, {'lat': 53.246193, 'lng': 10.354538}, {'lat': 53.2435, 'lng': 10.35903}, {'lat': 53.2417, 'lng': 10.35903}], 'holes': [[{'lat': 53.2426, 'lng': 10.372506}, {'lat': 53.2426, 'lng': 10.375501}, {'lat': 53.2417, 'lng': 10.376999}, {'lat': 53.239902, 'lng': 10.376999}, {'lat': 53.239006, 'lng': 10.375501}, {'lat': 53.239006, 'lng': 10.372506}, {'lat': 53.239902, 'lng': 10.371009}, {'lat': 53.2417, 'lng': 10.371009}, {'lat': 53.2426, 'lng': 10.372506}]]}], 'properties': {}}]}

Comment: What you have here is non-conformant JSON (the apostrophes should be quotes). I suggest you make an effort to learn how to use the software, instead of just announcing to professionals that you are clueless.

Comment: Your data looks like a Python dictionary. You can view it with a text editor like Notepad++ with a JSON viewer.  That will show you that you have nested objects and arrays of objects (points).   You will have to unpack that with code like python or Java.  You are clearly not clueless, you just need to be pointed at a few tutorials.

Answer (score 3):

The data looks like latitude longitude data (EPSG:4326).  If it is still in an Excel file you could Export it to a CSV.

1. Export your data to a csv (comma separated values) file.
2. With QGIS start a new project.
3. Add a basemap. => Layer > Add Layer > Add XYZ Layer
4. Add your csv file data. => Layer > Add Layer > Add Delimited Text layer
5. Choose what column is Longitude and which is Latitude
6. Select your Coordinate reference system (CRS)
7. Click 'Add' button.
8. Watch this video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NHolzMgaqwE

If your data posted here is in it's original form then it's a dictionary of shapes (Shells and holes) you may have to write some code to get the latitude and longitude out of it (or painstakingly manually extract it).  Then you can organize it into a csv to import.
Your code would look something like this:

```
import csv
import json
shapes = {'shell': [{'lat': 53.2417, 'lng': 10.35903}, {'lat': 53.240803, 'lng': 10.360527}, {'lat': 53.240803, 'lng': 10.363522}, {'lat': 53.238106, 'lng': 10.368014}, {'lat': 53.23721, 'lng': 10.366517}, {'lat': 53.23721, 'lng': 10.363522}, {'lat': 53.23631, 'lng': 10.362024}, {'lat': 53.235413, 'lng': 10.363522}, {'lat': 53.235413, 'lng': 10.378496}, {'lat': 53.232716, 'lng': 10.382988}, {'lat': 53.23092, 'lng': 10.379993}, {'lat': 53.23002, 'lng': 10.381491}, {'lat': 53.23002, 'lng': 10.384485}, {'lat': 53.22822, 'lng': 10.387481}, {'lat': 53.229122, 'lng': 10.388978}, {'lat': 53.23092, 'lng': 10.388978}, {'lat': 53.231815, 'lng': 10.390475}, {'lat': 53.23002, 'lng': 10.39347}, {'lat': 53.231815, 'lng': 10.396464}, {'lat': 53.231815, 'lng': 10.39946}, {'lat': 53.232716, 'lng': 10.400957}, {'lat': 53.234512, 'lng': 10.400957}, {'lat': 53.235413, 'lng': 10.402454}, {'lat': 53.235413, 'lng': 10.405449}, {'lat': 53.238106, 'lng': 10.409942}, {'lat': 53.2435, 'lng': 10.409942}, {'lat': 53.244396, 'lng': 10.408444}, {'lat': 53.244396, 'lng': 10.405449}, {'lat': 53.245296, 'lng': 10.403952}, {'lat': 53.247093, 'lng': 10.403952}, {'lat': 53.24799, 'lng': 10.405449}, {'lat': 53.24799, 'lng': 10.408444}, {'lat': 53.24889, 'lng': 10.409942}, {'lat': 53.250687, 'lng': 10.406946}, {'lat': 53.252483, 'lng': 10.406946}, {'lat': 53.253384, 'lng': 10.408444}, {'lat': 53.251587, 'lng': 10.411439}, {'lat': 53.252483, 'lng': 10.412936}, {'lat': 53.262367, 'lng': 10.396464}, {'lat': 53.262367, 'lng': 10.39347}, {'lat': 53.263268, 'lng': 10.391973}, {'lat': 53.265064, 'lng': 10.391973}, {'lat': 53.26596, 'lng': 10.390475}, {'lat': 53.265064, 'lng': 10.388978}, {'lat': 53.26147, 'lng': 10.388978}, {'lat': 53.26057, 'lng': 10.387481}, {'lat': 53.262367, 'lng': 10.384485}, {'lat': 53.262367, 'lng': 10.381491}, {'lat': 53.26147, 'lng': 10.379993}, {'lat': 53.25967, 'lng': 10.379993}, {'lat': 53.258774, 'lng': 10.378496}, {'lat': 53.258774, 'lng': 10.375501}, {'lat': 53.257874, 'lng': 10.374003}, {'lat': 53.256077, 'lng': 10.374003}, {'lat': 53.25518, 'lng': 10.375501}, {'lat': 53.25518, 'lng': 10.378496}, {'lat': 53.25428, 'lng': 10.379993}, {'lat': 53.25316, 'lng': 10.381491}, {'lat': 53.252483, 'lng': 10.374003}, {'lat': 53.25518, 'lng': 10.369512}, {'lat': 53.25518, 'lng': 10.363522}, {'lat': 53.249786, 'lng': 10.354538}, {'lat': 53.249786, 'lng': 10.351542}, {'lat': 53.24889, 'lng': 10.350045}, {'lat': 53.246193, 'lng': 10.354538}, {'lat': 53.2435, 'lng': 10.35903}, {'lat': 53.2417, 'lng': 10.35903}], 'holes': [{'lat': 53.2426, 'lng': 10.372506}, {'lat': 53.2426, 'lng': 10.375501}, {'lat': 53.2417, 'lng': 10.376999}, {'lat': 53.239902, 'lng': 10.376999}, {'lat': 53.239006, 'lng': 10.375501}, {'lat': 53.239006, 'lng': 10.372506}, {'lat': 53.239902, 'lng': 10.371009}, {'lat': 53.2417, 'lng': 10.371009}, {'lat': 53.2426, 'lng': 10.372506}]}
for key in shapes:
    print(key)
    point_list = []
    for point in shapes[key]:
        print(point['lat'], point['lng'])
        this_point = [point['lng'], point['lat']]
        point_list.append(this_point)
    try:
        outname = r"C:\Users\Cary\Desktop\Junk\TEST_" + str(key) + ".csv"
        with open(outname , 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
            writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
            for point in point_list:            
                writer.writerow(point)
        print(f"Wrote {outname}")

    except IOError:
        print("I/O error")
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The [Spreadsheet Layers](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/SpreadsheetLayers/) plugin is a handy tool that lets you skip the exporting to CSV step. A spreadsheet can be added directly using the familiar `Layer > Add Layer...` workflow.